# Disallowing google for a single url and its parameters in robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

i would like to disallow any urls starting with index.php except the following urls.

```
http://www.medikalyasam.com/index.php?do=catalog/start
http://www.medikalyasam.com/index.php?do=catalog/rebateProducts
http://www.medikalyasam.com/index.php?do=catalog/newProducts
```

Is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: Explicitly allow: the above urls at the top, then disallow: */index.php. I think that should work (although I'm not in a position to test it..

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: Create an answer that has the information from your comment. That way the OP can accept it.

Comment: I can not answer my own question, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly allow: the above urls at the top, then disallow: */index.php.